# How to interpret multi-conditional piecewise functions.

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, continuity

I'm trying to simulate hysteresis and the its inverse for a control problem.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwmmQ.jpg) is a model found in [Tao & Kokotovic, Adaptive Control Systems with Actuator and Sensor Nonlinearities] to generalize many types of hysteresis but i can't seen to figure what the second if statement in equations 2 and 3 means.
How to interpret it? How to implement it on Matlab?

More info: u(t) is output, v(t) is input; the rest of values is constant.

[Hysteresis figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWAEX.jpg)

The hysteresis model utilizes 8 parameters: 4 slopes and 4 intersections.

Top parameters have $_t$, left $_l$, bottom $_b$ and right $_r$. Middle uses $_d$ and $_u$. Sorry for the blurred picture.

$m_x$ are the slopes

$c_x$ is where the figure intersects the origin.

$c_d$ and $c_u$ are defined interactively with $c_d = u(t-1) - m_t*v(t-1) ; c_u = u(t-1) - m_b*v(t - 1)$

$v_1$ is the upper left corner defined as $v_1 = \dfrac{c_t+m_l*c_l}{m_l-m_t}$

$v_2$ is the lower right corner defined as $v_2 = \dfrac{c_b+m_r*c_r}{m_r-m_b}$

$v_3$ is the upper right corner defined as $v_3 = \dfrac{c_t+m_r*c_r}{m_r-m_t}$

$v_4$ is the lower left corner defined as $v_1 = \dfrac{c_b+m_l*c_l}{m_l-m_b}$

$v_d$ and $v_u$ are defined as $v_d = \dfrac{c_d+m_l*c_l}{m_l-m_t} ; v_u\dfrac{c_u + m_r*c_r}{m_r-m_b}$

Comment: What are all of the $m_x$ and $v_x$ and $c_x$terms? Maybe I can code it up in Mathematica and plot it, but those terms are not defined. Also what does$u(t) = H(v(t))$ mean?

Comment: I added more info about the function and a figure that shows how is the curve the function represents. $u(t) = H(v(t))$ means you are inputting $v(t)$ in the hysteresis function and getting $u(t)$ as a result.